# How do you automatically delete a file in a specified folder after 30 minutes after it's made?

Tags: windows-8

I have a folder where files automatically get saved.

I want to automatically delete a file in a specified folder 30 minutes after it's made (not delete all files every 30 minutes)

For example:

- File 1 gets made at 10:00.
- File 2 gets made at 10:15
- At 10:30 file 1 gets deleted
- At 10:45 file 2 gets deleted

This automatically happens to all files in a folder. Is this possible?

Comment: How real time do you want it?

Comment: Doesn't have to be exact. 30 minutes was just an example, I really don't care how often it happens as long as it happens once every few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this? It might work for you.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/autodelete-schedules-files-and-folders-deletion/

Answer (score 0):

You could easily program a solution, and have your process run in the background of the OS. Maybe try asking this on StackOverflow, or look into a programming language like C++.

Comment: Yes however I'm not interested in learning a programming language. Thanks though

Comment: I'm not aware of any freeware that does this, and there definitely isn't an option built into windows. You'll either have to search for freeware, hire a programmer, or build the program yourself. Good luck!